# Absolute positioning relative to absolute positioned parent

Tags: html, css

I know that when you want to position an element with "position:absolute" but still relative to it's parent you have to assign "position:relative" to the parent. However, in my case the parent itself has to have "position:absolute" which makes the child element positioned relatively to the page rather than the parent... Is there any solution for this?

Comment: You should really post your code. Generally when you poisition an element as absolute, it's childrens positions will relate to that element as if it was relative. It should be working just like that.

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect. An absolute positioned element is positioned with respect to it's closest *positioned* ancestor (i.e. something other than `static`). And as Ethnar said, you need to post the code you're having trouble with in your question.

Comment: You can start from [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/fzmhBq8WYTdPNRnHFdhD?p=preview)